# netCDF-java has trouble reading this netCDF file(format) and fetching values from the latlon dimension

Tags: raster, java, netcdf

I'm developing an application where I need to extract variable-values from netCDF files.

I'm processing several different formatted netCDF files and now one format seems to be creating some issues.

The problem is to correctly fetch data from lat/lon variables. Some lat/lon works, but the mapping does not seem to be complete.

ncdump of the netCDF file:

```
netcdf test2 {
dimensions:
        x = 182 ;
        y = 149 ;
        lev = 31 ;
        time = UNLIMITED ; // (72 currently)
variables:
        double lev(lev) ;
                lev:long_name = "generic" ;
                lev:units = "level" ;
                lev:axis = "Z" ;
        double time(time) ;
                time:standard_name = "time" ;
                time:units = "months since 1991-01-15 12:00:00" ;
                time:calendar = "standard" ;
        float variable1(time, lev, y, x) ;
                variable1:long_name = "Variable 1" ;
                variable1:units = "mg" ;
                variable1:_FillValue = 9.96921e+036f ;
                variable1:coordinates = "nav_lon nav_lat time lev" ;
        float nav_lon(y, x) ;
                nav_lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
                nav_lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        float nav_lat(y, x) ;
                nav_lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
                nav_lat:units = "degrees_north" ;

// global attributes:
                :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.5.1 (http://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdi)" ;
                :Conventions = "CF-1.0" ;
                :Title = "Test" ;
                :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.5.1 (http://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo)" ;
data:

 lev = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 ;

 time = 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121,
    122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135,
    136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149,
    150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163,
    164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177,
    178, 179 ;
}
```

I can also show you subset of the nav_lon data (from opendap) if that could be of help to understand the format:

```
Dataset {
    Float32 nav_lon[y = 4][x = 4];
} test2.nc;
---------------------------------------------
nav_lon[4][4]
[0], 78.00004, 80.0, 81.99996, 83.99992
[1], 78.00004, 80.0, 81.99996, 83.99992
[2], 78.00004, 80.0, 81.99996, 83.99992
[3], 35.53008, 36.53008, 37.53008, 38.53008
```

Now to the actual code that is not producing the desired results. I'm using the latest version of NetCDF-Java, 4.3.19:

```
public class TestReadNetCDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileURI = "URI_TO_THE_FILE";
        readNetCDFFile(fileURI);
    }

    private static void readNetCDFFile(String filename) {
        NetcdfDataset ncfile = null;
        try {
            ncfile = NetcdfDataset.openDataset(filename);
            GridDataset grid = new GridDataset(ncfile);
            System.out.println("GRID:" + grid);
            process(grid);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log("trying to open " + filename, ioe);
        } finally {
            if (null != ncfile)
                try {
                    ncfile.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    log("trying to close " + filename, ioe);
                }
        }
        NetcdfDataset.shutdown();
    }
    private static void process(GridDataset gds) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("VARS:");
        for (VariableSimpleIF v : gds.getDataVariables())
            System.out.println(v.getFullName());
        GridDatatype grid = gds.findGridDatatype("variable1");
        GridCoordSystem gcs = grid.getCoordinateSystem();
        double lat = -63.63;
        double lon = -14.83;
        //lat = -61.24769;
        //lon = 78.00004;
        lat = -77.7742;
        lon = 78.00004;

        // find the x,y index for a specific lat/lon position
        // xy[0] = x, xy[1] = y
        int[] xy = gcs.findXYindexFromLatLonBounded(lat, lon, null);

        // read the data at that lat, lon and the first time and z level (if any)
        // note order is t, z, y, x
        System.out.println("x,y:" + xy[0] + "," + xy[1]);
        Array data = grid.readDataSlice(0, 0, xy[1], xy[0]);
        // we know its a scalar
        double val = data.getDouble(0);

        System.out.printf("Value at %f %f == %f%n", lat, lon, val);
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that findXYindexFromLatLonBounded gets the wrong x/y indices (on most input values). If I drop "bounded", then it will fetch -1, -1, even though the latlon are within the "range" - though the mapping does not seem to be complete.

I could mention that ncWMS can read these files just fine and I can display the files as a WMS (and get point data out from there, but that is really inefficient and I'd like something better). [Thredds](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/) can also read the files and output them through i.e. OpenDAP or Godiva2. If I use the OpenDAP URL it provides the same result as if I use the nc-file URI.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I cant tell if the lat / lon 2D arrays are correct, or if you are seeing a bug.

One way to test is to bring it up in the ToolsUI ([example given](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/v4.3/webstart/netCDFtools.jnlp)).

Go to FeatureType / Grids, open the dataset and see what the grid looks like by hitting the red alien button (twice).

Publishing the dods URL lets others look at it remotely; you should also send what version of netcdf-java you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I won't have access to the data-set, and make it public accessible, before Monday, I will do that then. I'm using latest version of NetCDF-Java, 4.3.19.